# How can I define a port extender MCP23s17 pin in Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

My task is to use a port extender (MCP23s17) to drive a touch keypad for which I have to define names of pins so that I can call those names in arguments of a function.

I have searched for different methods to define "PORT EXTENDER" pin but could not find any satisfactory results. Kindly help me handle the situation.

i have used the following libraries downloaded from Arduino playground
1. CapacitiveSensor.h
2. MCP23S17.h
Now I have to use MCP23S17 Pin in the following function

```
#define key1 2
#define key2 4
CapacitiveSensor cs_4_2=Capacitivesensor(key2,key1);  //capacitive sensor is connected to pin 4 and 2
```

key1 and key2 are Arduino's pins. I want some method by which I can refer key1 and key2 to the port extender's (MSP23S17) pin. The above answers are surely helpful but they doesn't fulfill my requirement.

Thanks in Advance
Sorry for English.

Comment: It all depends which library you are using.

Comment: It is not clear what your question is about. It makes me wonder if this is a school assignment which you did not understand or you just simply don't know how to describe your problem. In any case, you have to provide more details: wiring, code you have written so far... In particular the sentence "I have to define names of pins so that I can call those names in arguments of a function" is not clear; maybe you could give the prototype of the function as you imagine it, that would give us food for thought.

Comment: i have to use multiple touch keypads with arduino via a port extender. I have managed to operate both the sensors and the port extender individually but when i came to combine them i faced a problem that when i call the library of touch keypads, i have to pass them the pin numbers on which they are connected. in my case i have connected them with port extender via SPI. i am confused how to refer port extender pin number because if i simply type a pin number, arduino will refer to its own pins.

Comment: You may have to edit the touch keypad library's code or write your own to use the port expander's pins instead of the Arduino's own pins.

Answer (score 1):

If you use this [arduino library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MCP23S17#pinMode):

```
#define LED_PIN 15

mcp.pinMode(LED_PIN, LOW); //set led pin on the MCP23S17 to an OUTPUT

mcp.digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [my library](https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/MCP23S17) you can do something like:

```
MCP23S17 expander1(&SPI, 10);

#define LED_PIN expander1, 15

void setPin(MCP23S17 &expander, int pin, bool level) {
    expander.digitalWrite(pin, level);
}

// ... later ...

setPin(LED_PIN, HIGH);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [Adafruit](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-MCP23017-Arduino-Library) Library, all do similar things, just in a slightly different way. I use this one, it just depends on which method you are most comfortable with and what your requirements are. Try them all and find out.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);  // debugging  
  mcp.begin();      // use default address 0

      for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        mcp.pinMode(trafficLights1[i], OUTPUT);
      }
       for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { 
        mcp.pinMode(trafficLights2[i], OUTPUT);
       }
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        mcp.pinMode(trafficLights3[i], OUTPUT);
        }
  for (int P=0;P<16;P++) {
    mcp.pullUp(P, HIGH);  // turn on a 100K pullup internally
    mcp.digitalWrite(P,LOW);
 }
      mcp.digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
}
```